# Gem not outputting the expected text

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

I've completed the **First Gem** section of [this tutorial](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/). However, in the **Requiring More Gems** section when I tried modifying my hola.rb as such:

```
class Hola
  def self.hi(language = :english)
    translator = Translator.new(language)
    translator.hi
  end
end

require 'hola/translator'
```

and added this translator.rb file:

```
class Hola::Translator
  def initialize(language)
    @language = language
  end

  def hi
    case @language
    when :spanish
      "hola mundo"
    else
      "hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

If I typed in these commands in IRB, I should get identical outputs:

```
% irb -Ilib -rhola
irb(main):001:0> Hola.hi(:english)
=> "hello world"
irb(main):002:0> Hola.hi(:spanish)
=> "hola mundo"
```

However, I'm not getting proper results. I tried modifying my gemspec and reinstalling the gem, but no success. What do you think I did wrong in this case?

```
stanley@ubuntu:~/Github/webdev_class/ruby/hola_stanley/lib$ irb -Ilib -rhola
irb(main):001:0> Hola.hi(:english)
=> "hello world"
irb(main):002:0> Hola.hi(:spanish)
=> "hello world"
irb(main):003:0> quit
```

Comment: It's odd because I tried the same code as you (copy/paste) and it worked as expected. Try simply by opening `irb` and manually requiring your lib.

Comment: @SamyDindane: Thanks. Will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, what's wrong, but are you sure there was no type and you requested the file you expected?

I would modify the code a bit:

```
class Hola::Translator
  def initialize(language, exceptions = false)
    @language = language
    @exceptions = exceptions
  end

  def hi
    case @language
    when :spanish
      "hola mundo"
    when :english
      "hello world"
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Unsupported language #{@language.inspect}" if @exceptions
      "hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

You support two languages: Spanish and English. Other languages are detected and you can select, if you get an error or an alternative (english) text.

You can start it with:

```
   class Hola
     def self.hi(language = :english)
       translator = Translator.new(language, true) ## <-- Modified
       translator.hi
     end
   end

   require 'hola/translator'
```

One advantage of the expection: You can see, which file really calls the exception.

Some other remarks:

- I would recommend to define `Hola` as a module, not a class.
- Instead the `raise` you could define a logger and report an error.

Example:

```
require 'log4r'
module Hola
  LOG = Log4r::Logger.new('Hola')
  class Translator
    def initialize(language)
      @language = language
    end

    def hi
      case @language
      when :spanish
        "hola mundo"
      when :english
        "hello world"
      else
        LOG.error("Unsupported language #{@language.inspect}")
        "hello world"
      end
    end
  end

  def self.hi(language = :english)
    translator = Translator.new(language)
    translator.hi
  end

end #module Hola

p Hola.hi
p Hola.hi(:english)
p Hola.hi(:spanish)
p Hola.hi(:german)

puts "Activate Hola-warnings"
Hola::LOG.outputters << Log4r::StdoutOutputter.new('stdout')
p Hola.hi
p Hola.hi(:english)
p Hola.hi(:spanish)
p Hola.hi(:german)
```

After activating the logger, you are informed, if you have a type in `:spanish` (that's the error I would expect).

Comment: I'll give your suggestion a try and report on how it goes.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I tried running the last example using the Ruby command: https://gist.github.com/5595e74231002e14c93f Any thoughts?

Comment: I just tried the code and it worked fine for me. I can reproduce (more or less) the error message, when I add a space between `:` and `spanish`. Did you take the code with cut+paste or are there some changes? Can you upload your testfile to check if there are copy-errors?